# SpringBoot 2.1.0 throws ClassNotFoundException when trying to integrate database access

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, byte-buddy

I have a simple `SpringBoot 2.1.0` application and try to add the database-connectivity with `JPA`. Everything is set up with the "`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`" dependency in `pom.xml`, but when I start the application, I get this `ClassNotFoundException`.

I tried already adding byte-buddy manually as dependency, but this changes nothing.

Has someone solved this problem already?

Many thanks for every hint in advance!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatchers
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatchers
at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.<clinit>(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:43)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:357)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:352)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:246)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:78)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:67)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:202)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
... 16 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 31 common frames omitted
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And here is the database-configuration in application.yml

```
spring
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    username: postgres
    password: <something>
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: The pom file would be helpful.

Comment: If you've upgraded the spring boot version, please try to delete .m2 folder and try again. If the project is new, please add the pom file and mention which type of connector did you use - embedded or external database.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/80).

Comment: I updated the issue with the dependencies from pom.xml and the database-configuration (external database)

Comment: I made some further hints:
The combination JDK 10.0.2 and SpringBoot 2.1.0 and JDK 11 with SpringBoot 2.0.6/2.1.0 produces these errors.

Answer (score 8):

Byte Buddy is used by Hibernate. By forcing Byte Buddy into *test* scope, the library is now missing at runtime.

Comment: Thank you. Had the same problem and removing the test scope for ByteBuddy in the POM fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

add dependency in pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy-dep</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I removed the folder for `hibernate` from the path

```
C:\Users\<Your user>\.m2\repository\org
```

Also deleted the folder `net\bytebuddy`

In eclipse, Right Click on the project and then Maven -> Update Project

Answer (score 1):

For me helped adding the following to the `module-info.java` file:

```
requires net.bytebuddy;
```

This is only applicable for applications with Java 9 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding as dependency in module.xml helped.

```
<dependencies> 
  <module name="net.bytebuddy"/> 
</dependencies>
```

It already comes with hibernate5 but I was not seeing the dependency.