# byte-budy not found when starting my Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, byte-buddy, java-module

I have a Spring Boot application that successfully starts when run with `mvn spring-boot:run` but when I try to run it from IntelliJ it crashes in the middle of starting up with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers
```

The full error is:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\jbr\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=65274:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Project\code\projectserver\target\classes;C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Project\code\projectcommon\target\classes;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.9.3\jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.9\jackson-core-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.9\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.9\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.9\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.2.0\HikariCP-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.28\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.11.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.2-GA\javassist-3.23.2-GA.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.16\byte-buddy-1.9.16.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.10.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.1.10.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-security-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-actuator\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-actuator-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-core\1.1.6\micrometer-core-1.1.6.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.9\HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\latencyutils\LatencyUtils\2.0.3\LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.8.jre7\postgresql-42.2.8.jre7.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.63\bcprov-jdk15on-1.63.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\flywaydb\flyway-core\5.2.4\flyway-core-5.2.4.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\io\sentry\sentry-spring\1.7.27\sentry-spring-1.7.27.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\io\sentry\sentry\1.7.27\sentry-1.7.27.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\newrelic\agent\java\newrelic-agent\5.7.0\newrelic-agent-5.7.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.9\commons-lang3-3.9.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.10\jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.26\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\9.0.24\tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.24.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.26\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.26\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.9.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.1.6.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar -m com.example.projectserver/com.example.projectserver.ProjectServerApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                        

2019-10-02 08:22:07.508  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.d.ProjectServerApplication           : Starting ProjectServerApplication on Utopia-Planitia with PID 6188 (C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Project\code\projectserver\target\classes started by pupeno in C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Project\code\projectserver)
2019-10-02 08:22:07.508  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.d.ProjectServerApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-02 08:22:07.523  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-10-02 08:22:07.523  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-10-02 08:22:08.715  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-10-02 08:22:08.855  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 140ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2019-10-02 08:22:09.199  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a23db6f6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-10-02 08:22:09.508  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-02 08:22:09.539  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-02 08:22:09.539  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.26]
2019-10-02 08:22:09.586  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-02 08:22:09.586  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2063 ms
2019-10-02 08:22:09.898  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
2019-10-02 08:22:09.898  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-10-02 08:22:09.992  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-10-02 08:22:09.992  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/project_dev (PostgreSQL 11.4)
2019-10-02 08:22:09.992  WARN 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.c.internal.database.base.Database    : Flyway upgrade recommended: PostgreSQL 11.4 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.
2019-10-02 08:22:10.086  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": 0015
2019-10-02 08:22:10.086  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2019-10-02 08:22:10.226  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-10-02 08:22:10.258  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {[WORKING]}
2019-10-02 08:22:10.258  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-10-02 08:22:10.258  WARN 6188 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatchers
2019-10-02 08:22:10.258  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-10-02 08:22:10.316  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-10-02 08:22:10.318  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-02 08:22:10.320  INFO 6188 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-02 08:22:10.335 ERROR 6188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatchers
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.example.projectserver/com.example.projectserver.ProjectServerApplication.main(ProjectServerApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at spring.boot.devtools@2.1.8.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatchers
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.<clinit>(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.11.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:na]
    at spring.orm@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.orm@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.orm@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.orm@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.orm@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm using OpenJDK 11 in this case:

```
> java --version
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

I also tried OpenJDK 13 with the same result:

```
openjdk 13 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I tried adding the bytebuddy dependencies explicitly, just in case, due to this [SpringBoot 2.1.0 throws ClassNotFoundException when trying to integrate database access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306613/springboot-2-1-0-throws-classnotfoundexception-when-trying-to-integrate-database), but then I get a different error:

```
Information:java: compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.4, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
Information:java: java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\pupeno\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-dep\1.10.1\byte-buddy-dep-1.10.1.jar
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:647)
... Backtrace cut due to Stack Overflow's size limit
Information:java: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byte.buddy.dep: Invalid module name: 'byte' is not a Java identifier
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.Checks.requireModuleName(Checks.java:52)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$Builder.<init>(ModuleDescriptor.java:1550)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.newAutomaticModule(ModuleDescriptor.java:2438)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.deriveModuleDescriptor(ModulePath.java:507)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:643)
Information:java:   ... 49 more
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'projectserver'
Information:javac 11.0.4 was used to compile java sources
Information:Module "projectserver" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:2019-10-02 08:24 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5 s 621 ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

Any ideas what's going on with this particular jar or what to try to get it to work?

Rafael Winterhalter, author of Byte Buddy, suggest this might be a bug on IntelliJ and I have already report it to them. One thing that gives me pause is that this library is required by Spring Boot itself, not my application:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.16:test
```

That would mean no Spring Boot application can run in Java >= 9 on IntelliJ. Surely I'm not the first one to hit this combination. Is there something else on my app that's causing it?

Comment: @michalk Java 11, I'll add the details to the question.

Comment: nevermind I found the version in the log - was not straight visible.

Comment: Could you please file an issue with a sample project at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Did you get and satisfiable answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that this has something to do with the module descriptor that ships with Byte Buddy. The library's `module-info.class` is located in `META-INF/versions/9`, the designated folder for multi-release jars, to avoid disrupting applications running on older JVM versions. This was quite an issue when Byte Buddy shipped the module-info in the root package.

Supposedly, this class file should be ignored by class loaders that do not support multi-release jars what is not normally an issue since only the JVM built-in class loader processes module descriptors, normally.

I see a lot of `org.jetbrains.jps` in your stack trace. I'd argue that this is a problem of your IDE not treating multi-version modular jars correctly. What happens if you run this application directly?

Comment: Thank you for the answer Rafael. If I run the application from the command line it works. I can add the log output for that case but I'm not sure it adds much. I'm trying to get it to work from IntelliJ now, so that I can properly debug it.

Comment: Make sure to report an issue with them.

Comment: Yes, I did, but, another Spring Boot application does run and Spring Boot depends on Byte Budy, so, it can't be just an bug in IntelliJ.

Comment: Could you add the startup command line of the process which IntelliJ prints in the very beginning?

Answer (score 1):

From the debug output of `mvn spring-boot:run`, it seems that Maven starts the JVM in the classpath mode. IDEA starts the app in the module path mode (see the use of `-mp` and `-m` options in the very first line of the log). Unfortunately, Spring Boot components aren't quite ready for that.

The particular problem with ByteBuddy is described in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-a-spring-boot-app-to-java-9-modules) (section "Javassist Failure"); there is also a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792088/java-module-system-why-do-we-need-to-explicitly-specify-the-default-modules-in) with Tomcat.